# Convert USB (HID) Full Speed to Low Speed

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host, hid

I want to connect a KVM-over-IP device to the console of my USB KVM switch to make it IP capable. The KVM-over-IP device offers a USB Full Speed composite device with keyboard and mouse subdevices, both capable of the HID boot protocol. When I connect it to the KVM switch's USB console host, it does not forward the inputs.

To find out why it is not working, I connected different USB input devices to the KVM switch, and it seems to only accept Low Speed simple, composite and compound devices. Another USB KVM switch made by another manufacturer behaves the same. So I think it is common for many KVM switch's HID emulation to expect Low Speed HID input devices, probably using the HID boot protocol.

From what I found out, it is impossible to force a Full Speed device to use Low Speed. This would need a bunch of modifications:

- The internal pull-up resistor needs to be moved from D+ to D-
- The logic levels of D+ and D- need to be inverted
- The clock needs to be divided by 8
- The packet payload size needs to be limited to 8 Bytes

The first two points could be addressed by an electrical adapter which swaps D+ and D-, but the second two points cannot be changed because it needs a modification in the proprietary firmware of the device, which I cannot access.

Is there a device or project, which is able to convert USB HID Full Speed to Low Speed for both keyboard and mouse (and maybe more device types)? So far I found those projects which could serve as a starting point:

- The [MouseKeyboardForward Example](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/USBHost_t36/blob/master/examples/MouseKeyboardForward/MouseKeyboardForward.ino) for the Teensy 3.6/4.x, but I am not sure if the USB clock of those devices can be divided by 8.
- The [hid-remapper](https://github.com/jfedor2/hid-remapper) based on the RP2040, used without mapping. If I understand it correctly from the datasheet, the USB clock can be divided by 8.

I am not sure if dividing the USB clock by 8 "bricks" the devices and blocks them from further program uploading using their push buttons. Both µCs are running in Full Speed at default.

Both projects are working on the HID protocol level and have no "return channel" to control the keyboard LEDs for caps lock, scroll lock and num lock. Maybe it would be easier to work on the USB packet level by implementing some input and output buffers and simply forward the packets in both directions? I doubt a simple keyboard/mouse Full Speed HID device is able to saturate a Low Speed connection, but I don't know if something would run in a timeout due to longer packet transmission times. The endpoint descriptors of the KVM-over-IP device tell me that the packet payload size is 8 Bytes, so at least this would not be an issue.

Any suggestions for a solution? Did I get something wrong in what I wrote? Any kind of input and help is very much appreciated!

Comment: *From what I found out, it is impossible to force a High Speed device to use Low Speed.* nah that's wrong. Any hispeed device must correctly register on a USB1 controller. However, it's not forced to offer comparable functionality (as that might simply be logically impossible) on the lower speed bus.

Comment: You're totally right! That reminded me that I actually confused the terms "High Speed" and "Full Speed" while writing my question, which I have already corrected. Thank you for the hint!